# Woocommerce Disable Persistent Cart for Specific User

Tags: woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site setup where I have once specific user created for an answering service. Because multiple 'customers' will be using this one account, I need to disable woocommerce's persistent shopping cart for one specific user ID so that if two operators are talking to two different customers at the same time on different computers, their shopping carts won't be linked. I have yet to see anywhere how I can turn off a persistent cart for woocommerce, let alone for specific users. Can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT:

After a lot of searching I found this great tutorial https://jhtechservices.com/woocommerce-persistent-cart-issue/ which I followed but doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please what does Persistent exactly mean here ?

Comment: i found some good explanation for this here https://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/6331814-persistent-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got everything working. Doing so required following  https://jhtechservices.com/woocommerce-persistent-cart-issue/ and then clearing the cookies and cache everywhere. Hopefully this'll help someone else!

Answer (score 4):

Woocommerce since 3.4 has special filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_persistent_cart_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/19027

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the user meta value with a filter - much better than deleting the value every time.

```
function disable_persistent_cart( $null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ) {

    if ( '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . get_current_blog_id() == $meta_key ) {

            if (get_current_user_id() === $the_user_id)
             return '';

    }

    return $null;

}

    add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'disable_persistent_cart', 10, 4 );
```